# Javascript relaying to HTML min, max, sum of an array, functions work fine individually but after one goes the rest return undefined or 0

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

As can be seen from the title I'm having some issues getting my code to work. If I choose min, max, or sum, they post the correct output but then the other two buttons return undefined for min/max if Sum was done first and return as 0 sum if min or max was chosen first. Any and all help is appreciated, apologies for my ignorance.
Here is what I've been working with:

```
function GetSum(){
     for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        number += arr[index];
    }

  return number;
} 
function ShowSum(){
    let sum = GetSum();
    if(arr = !isNaN && arr.length> 0){
      return sum;}
    ShowData("sum",sum);} //ShowData posts the sum to HTML page
function GetMaximum(){
    let i;
    var largest =arr[0];
    for(i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){ 
        if(arr[i]>largest) { largest = arr[i];
       }return largest;
 }console.log(largest); }
// this all works fine, then when other buttons are chosen it's no go
function ShowMax(){
    let maxNum = GetMaximum(arr);
    if(arr = !isNaN && arr.length> 0){
       
        return maxNum
        }  ShowData("max",maxNum);}
```

Why is ShowMax displaying the correct result, but unidentified when I've already used ShowSum?
It's the same testing in the console too. Same with ShowSum returning 0 once I've had a correct go with ShowMax. Thanks everybody

Comment: It looks as though you are doing a rather weird assignment to arr in ShowSum - if(arr = !isNaN && arr.length> 0) - I imagine you don't want to overwrite arr as it appears to be a global array used by the different functions.

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple problem, `isNaN()` is a function to check if string is number or not, then use `parseInt()` to convert string to number.

the `GetMaximum()` will not alyways return largest number because it set return in `for loop` and there will be remaining value.

```js
function GetSum() {
  let number = 0;
  for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
    if (!isNaN(arr[index]))
      number += parseInt(arr[index]);
  }
  return number;
}

function ShowSum() {
  let sum = 0;
  if (arr.length > 0) {
    sum = GetSum();
  }
  ShowData("sum", sum);
  return sum;
}

//ShowData posts the sum to HTML page
function GetMaximum() {
  let i, largest = 0;
  for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let num = isNaN(arr[i]) ? 0 : parseInt(arr[i]);
    if (num > largest) {
      largest = parseInt(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  //console.log(largest);
  return largest;
}

function ShowMax() {
  let maxNum = 0;
  if (arr.length > 0) {
    maxNum = GetMaximum(arr);
  }
  ShowData("max", maxNum);
  return maxNum
}

function ShowData(...args) {
  return console.log(args.join(' '))
}
var arr = [2.3, 6, 8, 1];
ShowMax()
ShowSum()
```